# Object with items : View-Controller communication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So, I have no clue how to search for an answer to this problem, mainly because there are several aspects to it which I don't know how to solve. So - here it is.

I have an object, let's call it **ObjectWithItems** which has a `List<Item>` of **Item** objects. Both have separate Views and Controllers (which seems logical to me, but I can't be sure).

What I'm trying to achieve is this – go to Create action of **ObjectWithItemsController** and fill the necessary information specific to it. Then, I click an `ActionLink` "Add item", which takes me to the Create action of the **ItemController**. The View is rendered and I enter information for that specific **Item**.

What I don't know how to do is the following: when I submit the current **Item**, it should be passed to the former Create view of the **ObjectWithItems** and added to the `List<Item>`. Furthermore, it should contain the information inputted before calling the **Item** Create method and the rendering of the corresponding View.

I know this is a bit blurry description, but that is because I have just started learning ASP MVC and still don't know what's what. Any tested approaches for this?

Comment: Do you have a database behind this ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Yes, I do. I am using EF.

Comment: Well, the simple way is to add your new item right away in the db, when you get back to your ObjectWithItem, normaly the new object would appear ?

Comment: Yes, but this is for a university project, and one of the implementational requests is that all of the Items are saved in one transaction, so saving them one at a time and returning when a new one is added is unfortunately not an option. That is why I'm struggling here...

Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Are you allowed to create temporary table ? Or use the Session["Key"] object ? Because if you don't use one of these two options well... what your asked to do is really bad... Usually you don't tranfer a whole model from a page to an other eternaly cause is a bad practice

Comment: I suppose. The only restrictions are that Items are saved under one transaction (all at the same time, that is) and that the Controller has no knowledge about them, meaning they are stored in a ObjectWithItems object. I know it is bad practice, but I chose MVC because I want to learn about it, so I have to bend it a little to the requirements.

Comment: I would personnaly use Session["key"] object, this will save anything as long as you don't reach the timeout

Comment: Ok. I will read about it and use that. I suppose I am allowed to. Thank you very much. If you put that comment in an answer, I will except it.

Comment: You can do all this in one view and action - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) for an example. Other wise you must first save the parent and pass its ID to the method that creates the child item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Session["key"] object allow you to store any kind of object, Ex :

```
List<Table> Rows = db.Table.Where(t => t.id < 100).ToList(); // 100 first rows

Session["TableRows"] = Rows;
```

And later when you want to retreive them :

```
List<Table> Rows = (List<Table>)Session["TableRows"] // don't forget to cast it
```

Your objects will exist in Session as long as you don't reach the ASP timeout

Comment: @dzenesiz if you need more infos or something borthers you, just ask me

Comment: Just so you know - this solved my problem perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score -2):

Communication between View-controller is done through HTTP Post of the form.

```
< form class="form-horizontal" method="post" >
or @using (Html.BeginForm())
```

[More info here with example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-helpers-forms-and-validation)

Comment: That doesn't help at all. I know how to submit a form, everything after that is what I'm interested in.